# Why is Django-CMS not directly linking to my Cloudfront CDN and getting 404's for CKEditors static files?

Tags: django, ckeditor, amazon-cloudfront, django-cms

I am trying to set up hosting for a DjangoCMS application using AWS. I'm currently utilizing Cloudfront with S3 as the CDN for media and static files, however, I've run into trouble when trying to use the ckeditor inside of the CMS plugins. I will get 404 errors that prevent it from loading at all. This is because Django CMS appears to be inappropriately building the URL's for ckeditor's static files.

The urls look like this:

```
http://example.com/en/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/my.cloudfront.net/static/djangocms_text_ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css/change/
```

When not using the CDN and storing the files locally it looks like DjangoCMS creates a 304 redirect to the proper location, but when using a CDN it seems to be mangling the url for some reason.

Is there anyway to configure the way DjangoCMS is building this url, or some standard way to implement CDN's for DjangoCMS that I may be mishandling? The current way I have the CDN setup is to have Django redirect static and media requests to the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

You just need to override the "TEXT_CKEDITOR_BASE_PATH" in settings.py.

TEXT_CKEDITOR_BASE_PATH = 'https://%s/djangocms_text_ckeditor/ckeditor/' % STATIC_URL